# Web page with FB application totally empty (blank) at Mac (Safari as well as FF), although it is OK at PC (including Safari)

Tags: facebook, macos

Does anyone have some idea, why application

https://www.facebook.com/balconi.cz/app_329635017093632 
or
https://apps.facebook.com/posli-dortik-balconi/

is not being viewed at Mac OS?
It is totally blank page there.

It is not function nor at Safari nor at FF on Mac.
But it is OK at all common browsers at PC, including Safari.

edit: I do not use any flash there, so flash is not a reason.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: So move it to correct thread, I do not even see  in which topic it is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work for me on Windows, either.

And that’s because you’re trying to display the auth dialog inside of an iframe — which Facebook does not allow (unless you already have an access token and supply it within the dialog URL). They send an HTTP response header saying this page should not be displayed inside of an iframe, and modern browsers respect that header.

Use JavaScript to redirect the top window to the address of the auth dialog:

```
top.location.href = "…{url}…";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it has soluted the situation.